# Access ElasticCache - Jedis and spring

Tags: spring, spring-data, jedis, amazon-elasticache

We are just starting on AWS and have requirement to use AWS ElasticCache with Redis-jedis with Spring.
Spring-data-redis 1.8.8.RELEASE
aws-java-sdk 1.11.228
Spring 4.2.9.RELEASE
jedis 2.9.0

I was able to connect and cache data to local redis with below code. I have tried making code changes as https://github.com/fishercoder1534/AmazonElastiCacheExample/tree/master/src/main/java , but not been successful. Would really appreciate some guidance and help with some sample code. 
AWS ElasticCache is currently configured as option 1, but would also need to go to option 2 soon.
1. Non-replicated cluster - Redis cluster-disabled with no replicas 
2. Replicated cluster - Redis cluster-enabled and Redis cluster disabled with read replicas.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
// @PropertySource("classpath:/redis.properties")
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
// private @Value("${redis.host}") String redisHost;
// private @Value("${redis.port}") int redisPort;

//@Bean
  public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
    return new KeyGenerator() {
      @Override
      public Object generate(Object o, Method method, Object... objects) {
        // This will generate a unique key of the class name, the method name, and all method parameters appended.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(o.getClass().getName());
        sb.append(method.getName());
        for (Object obj : objects) {
          sb.append(obj.toString());
        }
        return sb.toString();
      }
    };
  }


@Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();

    // Defaults for redis running on Local Docker 
    redisConnectionFactory.setHostName("192.168.99.100");
    redisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379);

    return redisConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
    RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer()); 
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate) {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);

    // Number of seconds before expiration. Defaults to unlimited (0)
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(1200);
    cacheManager.getCacheNames().forEach(cacheM-> {System.out.println(cacheM);});
    return cacheManager;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Implemented Caching with AWS Elastic Cache + Lettuce (Redis java Client) + spring-data-redis. 3 master with 2 slaves and SSL using spring @Cachable and @CacheEvict annotation. Please provide any inputs if you see any issue or it can be done in a better way.

```
Spring  4.3.12.RELEASE
Spring-data-redis   1.8.8.RELEASE
aws-java-sdk    1.11.228
Lettuce (Redis java Client) 4.4.2.Final

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
long expirationDate = 1200;

static AWSCredentials credentials = null;
static {
    try {
        //credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("default").getCredentials();
        credentials = new SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Got exception..........");
        throw new AmazonClientException("Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. "
                + "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct "
                + "location (/Users/USERNAME/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.", e);
    }       
}

@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    AmazonElastiCache elasticacheClient = AmazonElastiCacheClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
    DescribeCacheClustersRequest dccRequest = new DescribeCacheClustersRequest();
    dccRequest.setShowCacheNodeInfo(true);

    DescribeCacheClustersResult clusterResult = elasticacheClient.describeCacheClusters(dccRequest);

    List<CacheCluster> cacheClusters = clusterResult.getCacheClusters();
    List<String> clusterNodes = new ArrayList <String> ();
    try {
        for (CacheCluster cacheCluster : cacheClusters) {
            for (CacheNode cacheNode : cacheCluster.getCacheNodes()) {
                String addr = cacheNode.getEndpoint().getAddress();
                int port = cacheNode.getEndpoint().getPort();
                String url =  addr + ":" + port;
                if(<CLUSTER NAME>.equalsIgnoreCase(cacheCluster.getReplicationGroupId()))
                    clusterNodes.add(url);  
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisClusterConfiguration(clusterNodes));
    redisConnectionFactory.setUseSsl(true);
    redisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return redisConnectionFactory;
}

    @Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
    RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer()); 
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate) {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);

    // Number of seconds before expiration. Defaults to unlimited (0)
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(expirationDate);
    cacheManager.setLoadRemoteCachesOnStartup(true);
    return cacheManager;
}
```

}

Comment: This looks good so far! One question tho...how does the cache manager know which redis cache nodes are read only, and which ones are master?