# ElasticCache with Redis - Very Slow performance

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, spring-data-redis, lettuce

We have implemented caching with AWS ElastiCache + redis with both **Encryption in-transit and Encryption at-rest** enabled using Spring-data-redis and Lettuce with SSL.

Spring  4.3.12.RELEASE
Spring-data-redis   1.8.8.RELEASE
aws-java-sdk    1.11.228
Lettuce (Redis java Client) 4.4.2.Final

Code for Implementation is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314725/access-elasticcache-jedis-and-spring/47515549#47515549). We are caching data retrieved from SQL queries. 
The application runs very slow with above implementation in comparison to when caching is not implemented. 
Appreciate any help, to improve performance.

Thanks, Raj

Answer (score 1):

There are could be several reasons for slowness:

- Network performance. If the size of objects is large, the network performance of the cache instances as well as client instances matters.
- A large number of fields in the objects. Spring data stores each field separately in redis and then assembles the object on retrieval.

Comment: After trying out different options, I can say because of the #2, Appreciate any help with eliminating spring data redis.